# Better approach for fetching property data from Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have many (100's of) property values that I have kept in externalized application.properties file.
As per doc there  3 ways to fetch:

1. Read application.properties using `Environment` object,
2. Read a property from application.properties file using `@ConfigurationProperties`
3. reading a property using the `@Value` annotation.

Which is the best approach and what are advantages/disadvantages over each other in terms of design?

Comment: If you follow your mentioned approaches, you have to create that many properties to assign values. With 100's of properties, it is very difficult to get the job done. Apache commons has CompositeConfiguration class in which you can load a property file and you can get the value by using compositeConfig.getProperty(keyName)

Answer (score 2):

*Super short answer:* **It depends**.

*Short answer:* Use a mix of all three.

*Long answer:*

With that many properties (100+), it would be fair to assume that they are not all about the same subject area, e.g. there might be properties for configuring email settings (SMTP host, password, ...), properties for configuring business rules, properties for web service endpoint addresses, ...

Centralizing all those properties in a single huge [`@ConfigurationProperties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html) object is a bad idea, because it breaks the [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) design principle.

So, guidelines:

- If your property names are dynamic, get them programmatically using [`Environment`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html)
- If multiple components need the same set of properties, use a `@ConfigurationProperties` bean.
- If your component only needs one or a few properties, use `@Value`
- If your component needs many properties, consider using a `@ConfigurationProperties` bean.

As with all guidelines, those are not hard rules, just suggestions. You can create a `@ConfigurationProperties` bean for a single property, if you want, but it's a bit of overkill, and you can have 10+ `@Value` annotated fields in a component, but consolidating them in a bean class might be better, especially if you need logic to interpret / post-process the property values.

Comment: Also: If you're reinventing stuff Boot provides out of the box (I just found out that it auto-configures a SendGrid API client if you provide the key!), stop reinventing and use the Boot-provided pieces.